# how to turn off the flash light in android automatically after two minutes

Tags: java, android

I am trying to on flash light and i want to off automatically after two minutes can anybody say how to turn off the flash light in android automatically after two minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on the Flashlight by using Following method in your MainActivity

```
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}
```

Turn off the Flashlight by Using the following Methods in your MainActivity:

```
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i want automatically turn off flash light code if it is possible please send that code

Comment: this code is enough i think, just put it in right place.